# Labels next to marking(s)

Tags: tikz-pgf

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{%
  tensionarrowreversed/.tip={%
    Triangle[length=2.5mm, width=2.5mm, open, reversed]
  },
  %
  %
  tensionarrow/.tip={%
    Triangle[length=2.5mm, width=2.5mm, open]
  },
  %
  %
  string/.style={%
    draw, color=blue,
    decoration={markings,
                mark= at position 0.75 with {\arrow{tensionarrowreversed}}},
                postaction={decorate},
    decoration={markings,
                mark= at position 0.25 with {\arrow{tensionarrow}}},
                postaction={decorate}
  },
  %
 }
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[string] (0, 0)--(0, 5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

In the above code, how can target the marking(s) and put label next to them? (The labels in the image are hand-put.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `pos` keyword to position a node at a fraction of the distance along a path.

Note also that there is a difference between having `reversed` in the arrow tip specifications, and using `\arrowreversed`. The former places the back end at the specified position, the latter places the tip at the specified position, as demonstrated below.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{%
  tensionarrowreversed/.tip={%
    Triangle[length=2.5mm, width=2.5mm, open, reversed, red] % note added red
  },
  %
  %
  tensionarrow/.tip={%
    Triangle[length=2.5mm, width=2.5mm, open]
  },
  %
  %
  string/.style={%
    draw, color=blue,
    decoration={markings, % you can have multiple arrow tips in one decoration
                mark=at position 0.25 with {\arrow{tensionarrow}},
                mark=at position 0.75 with {\arrowreversed{tensionarrow}}, % added this
                mark=at position 0.75 with {\arrow{tensionarrowreversed}}}, % same position as previous, but different arrow tip
                postaction={decorate},
  },
  %
 }
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[string] (0, 0)--(0, 5) node[right,pos=0.25] {Text} node[right,pos=0.75] {txeT};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```